# Render API data with express node to html/ handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, templates, handlebars.js

I need help with rendering data from a API to html/handlebars.

I am a little confused on how to display the data on the page

Here I is what I got so far :

**ROUTES FOLDER/FILE:**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const us_states = require('../us_state.js');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Find My Election', states: us_states });
});

/* GET Election List. */
router.post('/upcomingelections', function(req, res, next) {
        fetch(`https://api.turbovote.org/elections/upcoming?district-divisions=ocd-division/country:us/state:ma,ocd-division/country:us/state:ma/place:wayland
`, {
                method: 'get',
                headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' },
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => console.log(json));
  res.render('electionlist');
});

module.exports = router;
```

So far I've made the get request and the data is stored. then I use res.send to send the data to the handlebars page to be rendered.
None of the data I want is seen on the page. I can't figure out what I did wrong.
**HTML/HANDLEBARS FILE**
:

```
<div class="resultcontainer">
  <h1 class="resultTitle"> UPCOMING ELECTION(S)</h1> 
   <div id="wrapper">  
      <table id="keywords" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><span>Description</span></th>
            <th><span>Date</span></th>
            <th><span>Registration Deadline</span></th>
            <th><span>Election Level</span></th>
            <th><span>Website</span></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
            {{#if json}}
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="lalign"></td>
                        <td>{{{json.description}}}</td>
                        <td>{{{json.date}}}}</td>
                        <td>{{{json.district-divisions[0]['election-authority-level']}}}</td>
                        <a href={{{json.website}}}>link</a>
                      </tr>
                     </tbody> 
              {{else}}
                <p class="empty">No upcoming election</p>  
            {{/if}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait until `fetch` is done before rendering. Right now you're rendering without waiting, and you're not passing any data to `res.render`

Also you should always handle the error. Add a `.catch` to the promise chain, that way if the request fails you can end the request.

```
router.post('/upcomingelections', function(req, res, next) {
    fetch(`https://api.turbovote.org/elections/upcoming?district-divisions=ocd-division/country:us/state:ma,ocd-division/country:us/state:ma/place:wayland`, {
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
            console.log(json);

            res.render('electionlist', { json });
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(500).send(e.message));
});
```

Comment: wow, can't believe I forgot that. the data is coming back but isn't displayed on in the handlebar file

Comment: Show what data is, add the console log output. Maybe you're accessing it the wrong way.